# React nested route fails to load on refresh

Tags: reactjs, routes, http-status-code-404, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I have a React app with navigation powered by `react-router` that I run in development with `webpack-dev-server` and the history fallback option enabled. Here is the routes I have defined in my `index.js`

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRedirect to="/intro" />
      <Route path="/intro" component={Intro} />
      <Route path="/device" component={Device} />
      <Route path="/clothing" component={Clothing} />
      <Route path="/build" component={Build}>
        <IndexRedirect to="/build/pattern" />
        <Route path="/build/pattern" component={Pattern} />
        <Route path="/build/layout" component={Layout} />
        <Route path="/build/color" component={Color} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/capture" component={Capture} />
      <Route path="/review" component={Review} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

When I navigate through links, everything works fine and I can see the nested route components nesting within their parent route components as expected. For example when I navigate to `/build/color` I can see my `App` component nesting the `Build` component nesting the `Color` component.

Where it fails is when I try to hit the refresh button within the nested route. React entirely fails to load and I get the following error

> GET http://localhost:8080/build/app.js 404 (Not Found)

There is indeed not such a file in my app but I am still confused as of why it is automatically looking for this file instead of reloading the route from the root. Note that hitting refresh on pages like `/device` does work without an issue.

Let me know if you need more details about my setup.
Thanks!

---

**Solution:**

My `webpack` setup is actually using `HtmlWebpackPlugin` which was injecting the path to my app bundle as follows

`<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

All I needed to do was to configure my `webpack` public path as `publicPath: '/'` so that the bundle would be injected as follows

`<script src="/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It doesn't work because it can't load your javascript bundle. I'm guessing that the problem is with your path in script tag in HTML. Probably you have specified the path to app.js with dot at the beginning like this one
`<script src="./app.js"></script>`, if this is true please remove dot and check if the problem still exists `<script src="/app.js"></script>`

Let's illustrate what is the difference between `./app.js` and `/app.js`

Case 1. You are loading page using first level of routes like `/` or `/intro`

- `./app.js`: HTML tries to load script from `http://address/app.js`
- `/app.js`: HTML tries to load script from `http://address/app.js`

No difference

Case 2. You are loading page using second level of routes `/build/pattern`

- `./app.js`: HTML tries to load script from `http://address/build/app.js` - **doesn't exist**
- `/app.js`: HTML tries to load script from `http://address/app.js` - OK

Comment: My webpack setup currently injects my app bundle as `<script src="app.js"></script>` which yields a result similar to `./app.js` in my case. I just need to configure webpack to inject the absolute path to my bundle. If you also have the solution for that I would take it too :)

Comment: If you are using `HTML Webpack Plugin` to generate HTML you need to set `webpackConfig.output.publicPath = '/'`

Comment: This answer helped me find a solution to a similar issue with Express serving a React front end though index.html. I had to remove the `"homepage": "."` from my package.json files.

Comment: I had the same problem with React Router 6 and Vite. In my case I had to do the opposite, i.e to *add* the dot (and slash) in front of the path to my entrypoint: `<script type="module" src="./src/main.tsx"></script>`

Comment: I didn't have a dot or a slash: `<script type="module" src="main.jsx"></script>`. Changing to `src="/main.jsx"` fixed this problem for me. Thanks @niba for pointing me in the right direction! I was hopelessly looking at Vite config and how my routes were set up...

Answer (score 14):

@niba's answer perfectly solved my problem. I have been having the problem that when I nest a `<Route/>` element inside a component that is already being rendered by a `<Route/>`, it will fail to load the script bundle.js when I try to go to a sub-route url. After adding the following in the webpackConfig.json, everything is back to normal.

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: I was just missing the `publicPath: '/',`

Answer (score 3):

In `package.json` file, just set

```json
    "homepage": "/"
```

Comment: This worked for me! React hides all webpack configuration and the only problem I had was having "homepage": "./" so THANKS!

Comment: It worked for me and save a huge times, I had to use  "homepage": "./"

Answer (score 2):

For those who have tried the above and stil have issues, I'm using html-webpack-plugin on my webpack configuration, so it injects the bundle inside the HTML with no need to add any script import on index.html

So I **removed** the following line from my index.html file:

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

And added the following configuration on webpack plugins section:

```
// some other imports 
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
...
webpack default config
...

plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      hash: true,
      inject: true,
    }),
    ...
    other plugins,
  ],

}
```

Just remember to also use the output configuration accordingly to your project, such as mine:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
```