# server fall back and nested routes with react-router and url parameters

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, url-routing

In my react app I'm using react-router with `BrowserRouter`.
my webpack file has

```
devServer.historyApiFallback: true
```

I have a

```
<Route path='/details/:parameter' />
```

when navigating through the app, both the fallback and the route(s) work as expected.

However, if I'm on the route that serves at `/details/:parameter` and I refresh, the app breaks and tells me in the console that it can't find

```
/details/webpack_bundle.js
```

however the url in the browser still contains the correct route with its parameter.

I was hoping to find an elegant solution to this. Any explanation for why it's behaving this way is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

duplicate question: see [React nested route fails to load on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075024/react-nested-route-fails-to-load-on-refresh).

I'm using HTML Webpack Plugin in webpack and this is the solution I found.

```
webpackConfig.output.publicPath = '/'
```

this loads the bundle from the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

Open up your console and check if your getting an unexpected token error '<'

It's probably because in index file you're missing a slash '/' before the bundle.js. Change it to `<script src='/bundle.js'><script>`

Check out this answer: [Express.js, Unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743275/express-js-unexpected-token)